# Webcam Streaming is mirrored using OpenCV 3.0 + Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013, opencv3.0

Every time i compile this code the webcam streaming is mirrored like I lift up my right hand and it appears like if it was my left hand on the screen instead and after a couple of re-compiling an error message appeared and the code never worked again.

The error:
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFB3C6DA1C8 in Camera.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000D18AD5F610.

And no other option left except to break the process.

The code:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv\cv.h>

using namespace cv;


int main(){

    Mat image;

    VideoCapture cap;

    cap.open(1);

    namedWindow("Window", 1);

    while (1){

        cap >> image;

        imshow("window", image);

        waitKey(33);

   }


}
```

I don't know if something wrong with my code I've just started learning opencv !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv\cv.h>

using namespace cv;


int main(){

    Mat image;

    VideoCapture cap;

    cap.open(1);

    namedWindow("Window", 1);

    while (1){

        cap >> image;
        flip(image,image,1)
        imshow("window", image);

        waitKey(33);

   }


}
```

just Flip the image horizontally that will do [Find More Here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=flip#void%20flip(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20int%20flipCode))

Comment: It works nice with live stream but not with drawings letters or numbers .. in another code the stream was fixed but the letters were shifted to the left of the screen and mirrored !!

Comment: Then you use the fliped image to display and the original image to process .

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong when your image is mirrored on the vertical (/x) axis (I guess in your example you are using a built-in (laptop) webcam).

A (very) simple code for capturing and showing your image could be the following:

```
// imgcap in opencv3
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/videoio.hpp"

int main() {

    cv::VideoCapture cap(0); // camera 0
    cv::Mat img;
    while(true) {
        cap >> img;
        cv::flip(img,img,1);
        cv::imshow("live view", img);
        cv::waitKey(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When using OpenCV 3 you should include headers like:
`#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>`

Comment: I think you forgot the while (1) loop !